# Restructure table by removing NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-structures

I have a table in SQL that looks like this:

```
Customer   Product    1999     2000     2001    2002      2003
Smith      51         NULL     NULL       15      14      NULL
Jones      14           11        7     NULL    NULL      NULL
Jackson    13         NULL     NULL     NULL       3         9
```

The figures under each year column are amounts, in dollars.  Each customer has two consecutive years of amounts, and the rest of the years are zero.  I would like to re-structure this table so that instead of wide list of years, it just has two columns Amount-Year1 and Amount-Year2.  So it selects the two non-zero years and puts them in those columns, in the correct order.  This would greatly reduce the size of my table.

So far I've been able to re-structure it so that there is one amount column and one year column, but I then get multiple rows per customer, which unfortunately I can't have (due to downstream analysis).  Can anyone think of a way to get the two Amount-Year columns?

I would like the final table to look like this:

```
Customer    Product    Amount_Y1    Amount_Y2
Smith       51         15           14
Jones       14         11            7
Jackson     13          3            9
```

I don't mind that I lose the information about the specific years, as I can get that from another source.  The actual table has data for all years between 1999 and 2018, and there will be further years in the future.

Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Sorry, should've said - I'm using SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: If I need to re-structure this table, I would split into 2 tables- tblCust (CustID, CustName) and tblCustAmount (RowID, FK_CustID, Amount). This will help in future data reference and report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COALESCE` that will do the job for you. The query is dynamics so that if tomorrow year columns are changed, i.e. removed or added you do not have to change anything.

Sample query: (Assuming table to be table1 and column names to be same as year).

```
    DECLARE @columnsdesc nvarchar(max), @columnsasc nvarchar(max)
SET @columnsdesc = ''
SELECT @columnsdesc = (select + '[' +  ltrim(c.Name)  +   ']' + ','
FROM     sys.columns c 
         JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = c.object_id 
WHERE    o.type = 'U' and o.Name = 'table1' and c.Name not in ('Customer', 'Product')
ORDER BY c.Name desc for xml path ( '' ))

SET @columnsasc = ''
SELECT @columnsasc = (select + '[' +  ltrim(c.Name)  +   ']' + ','
FROM     sys.columns c 
         JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = c.object_id 
WHERE    o.type = 'U' and o.Name = 'table1' and c.Name not in ('Customer', 'Product')
ORDER BY c.Name asc for xml path ( '' ))
   SELECT @columnsasc = LEFT( @columnsasc,LEN(@columnsasc)-1)
   SELECT @columnsdesc = LEFT( @columnsdesc,LEN(@columnsdesc)-1)
   DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SET @sql = 'SELECT Customer, Product, COALESCE('+ @columnsasc  +') as Amount_Y1,
COALESCE(' + @columnsdesc +' ) as Amount_Y2
FROM Table1'

EXEC(@sql)
```

If you're dealing with a `temporary table`, then the code will change slightly:
Test it here: http://rextester.com/MRVR48808

```
DECLARE @columnsdesc nvarchar(max), @columnsasc nvarchar(max)
SET @columnsdesc = ''
SELECT @columnsdesc = (select + '[' +  ltrim(c.Name)  +   ']' + ','
FROM     tempdb.sys.columns c               --Changes here
         JOIN tempdb.sys.objects o ON o.object_id = c.object_id    --Changes here
WHERE    o.type = 'U' and o.Name like '#table1%' and c.Name not in ('Customer', 'Product')   --Changes here
ORDER BY c.Name desc for xml path ( '' ))

SET @columnsasc = ''
SELECT @columnsasc = (select + '[' +  ltrim(c.Name)  +   ']' + ','
FROM     tempdb.sys.columns c                   --Changes here
         JOIN tempdb.sys.objects o ON o.object_id = c.object_id     --Changes here 
WHERE    o.type = 'U' and o.Name like '#table1%' and c.Name not in ('Customer', 'Product')  --Changes here
ORDER BY c.Name asc for xml path ( '' ))
   SELECT @columnsasc = LEFT( @columnsasc,LEN(@columnsasc)-1)
   SELECT @columnsdesc = LEFT( @columnsdesc,LEN(@columnsdesc)-1)
   DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SET @sql = 'SELECT Customer, Product, COALESCE('+ @columnsasc  +') as Amount_Y1,
COALESCE(' + @columnsdesc +' ) as Amount_Y2
FROM #Table1'   --Changes here

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: I really like the idea of dynamic query to get the column names, but unfortunately I haven't been able to get the code to work.  I don't think you can use ORDER BY on derived tables?

Comment: I hear you.I have made the required changes and tested it, it works fine.
Alternatively, you can test it here: http://rextester.com/YGNE23015

Comment: Forgot to mention, I have also edited the answer to include the changes.

Comment: Dating back to at least the 2000 version of SQL Server, is [this warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "Do not use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (that is, to compute aggregate values). Unexpected query results may occur. This is because all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments) are not guaranteed to be executed exactly once for each output row". I've long argued it's on the wrong page but it does indicate that this technique shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: Thank you @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Honestly, I have never had issues using the earlier approach but glad you brought it up. I have made the further required changes to avoid the issue and tested it. 
Reference: Technet article to safely concatenate values and avoid issue indicated above:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28585.t-sql-safely-concatenate-values-into-a-scalar-variable.aspx

rw2: Please give it a shot and let me know how it goes. Also, I have updated it here: http://rextester.com/edit/YGNE23015

Comment: Many thanks Deepak Lakhotia, and @Damian for the warning.  I've been looking at the code - it works fine on the rextester site, but for some reason, when I copy it into my SSMS, I can't get it to output anything - it will just say "command completed successfully" but doesn't show any output or table anywhere...!

Comment: Please double check, if it still doesn't work please share screenshots of the table design and the query that you're running.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I was waiting to try it out on my work SQL server.  No, I still have the same problem.  I copy/pasted the code, with the only change being that I changed all references to "Table1" to "#Table1" as I don't have write permission.  I wonder if it's some setting on my SSMS.  It appears to run correctly, and says "Command(s) completed successfully", but no results appear.

Comment: It seems to be because I'm using #temp tables - apparently they disappear after dynamic queries are executed.

Comment: Change the part of the query where fetch the column names to something as below as you’re using temp tables:                     Select * from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id = object_id(‘tempdb..#table1’)

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out which bit I'm supposed to replace

Comment: In the original query, replace sys.columns to tempdb.sys.columns and O.Name = ‘Table1’ to O.Name=‘#Table1’     Both twice. I am replying from phone so not able to change original query and send you as of now. If it still doesn’t work, I will reply to you after 3 hours. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170142/discussion-between-rw2-and-deepak-lakhotia).

Comment: I have included the edits for a temporary table now. Hope it helps. If so, please upvote and mark it as an answer so that it can help others too.

Comment: Thanks DEEPAK LAKHOTIA, that is great, it works perfectly.  I'll upvote and mark as the correct answer.  Thanks to all others who answered too, they all worked, but this is my preferred option as it dynamically selects the column names.

Answer (score 3):

Thankfully `UNPIVOT` removes `NULL`s anyway, so we can do this with `UNPIVOT`/`ROWNUMBER()`,`PIVOT`:

```
declare @t table (Customer varchar(15),Product int,[1999] int,
                  [2000] int,[2001] int,[2002] int,[2003] int)
insert into @T(CUstomer,Product,[1999],[2000],[2001],[2002],[2003]) values
('Smith'  ,51,NULL,NULL,  15,  14,NULL),
('Jones'  ,14,  11,   7,NULL,NULL,NULL),
('Jackson',13,NULL,NULL,NULL,   3,   9)

;With Numbered as (
    select
        Customer,Product,Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer,Product
                           ORDER BY Year) rn
    from
        @t t
            unpivot
        (Value for Year in ([1999],[2000],[2001],[2002],[2003])) u
)
select
    *
from
    Numbered n
        pivot
    (SUM(Value) for rn in ([1],[2])) w
```

Results:

```
Customer        Product     1           2
--------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Jackson         13          3           9
Jones           14          11          7
Smith           51          15          14
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using COALESCE as follows : For one field from beginning to end and for the second in the reverse manner.

```
SELECT Customer,Product, COALESCE([1999],[2000],[2001],[2002],[2003]) as Y1, 
       COALESCE([2003],[2002],[2001],[2000],[1999])  as Y2
FROM  #TEMPDATA
```

Comment: Aswani - Can you make this dynamic as there could be  3 NON NULL values.

Comment: @Pawan Kumar In that case, what is the criteria for selecting two out of the three ?

Comment: Try this example - ('Jackson',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,5)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using `cross apply`:

```
select t.customer, t.product, v.Amount_Y1, v.Amount_Y2
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when which = 1 then val end) as Amount_Y1,
             max(case when which = 2 then val end) as Amount_Y2
      from (select val, yr, row_number() over (order by yr) as which
            from (values (t.[1999], 1999), (t.[2000], 2000), (t.[2001], 2001),
                         (t.[2002], 2002), (t.[2003], 2003)
                 ) v(val, yr)
            where val is not null
           ) v
```